# grunt browserSync: different tasks for different proxy urls

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, gruntjs, browser-sync

i have a shared gruntfile with browser sync set like this:

```
    browserSync: {
        dev: {
            bsFiles: {
                  src : ['export/style/app.css', 'export/javascript/app.js', 'export/**/*.html', 'export/**/*.shtml'],
            },
            options: {
                ghostMode: false,
                watchTask:true,
                proxy: "http://mywebsite.dev"
            },
        }
    }
```

and i use it with `grunt sync`

`grunt.registerTask('sync', ['less', 'postcss', 'uglify', 'concat', 'copy', 'browserSync', 'watch']);`

this proxy config works fine with me, but my colleagues with which i share this repo have different urls to proxy for that same project.

i tried creating a new task called `browserSync2`with a different url in the proxy like so: `proxy: mycolleaguewebsite.dev`and a different grunt task called `grunt sync2` and using this task

`grunt.registerTask('sync2', ['less', 'postcss', 'uglify', 'concat', 'copy', 'browserSync2', 'watch']);`

but it says it can't find the task.

how can i do this?

thanks! :)

Comment: Can you share the code with the new tasks you defined?

Comment: @gnerkus question updated